# History of quaternions representing rotations.

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, math-history, quaternions

I looked all over, but I cannot find anything about the history of representing rotations by quaternions.  Who first came up with this extremely clever idea?

Comment: FYI, in case you weren't aware of this other site, a question like this might be more appropriate to be asked on the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) SE site.

Comment: @JohnOmielan That hint helped me find https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.cma/1349803591.  Thank you.

Comment: Did you look in Wikipedia? The very first paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion answers your question. There’s a fairly lengthy “History” section farther down.

Comment: @amd I did look at Wikipedia.  That article discusses the history of quaternions, but it doesn't talk a lot about the history of the representation of rotations by quaternions.

Comment: The article given to me by @JohnOmielan is very helpful.  It looks like this representation is a combination of work by Rodrigues, Cauchy, and Hamilton.

Comment: And also Gauss worked on it in 1819, but his work wasn't published until 1900.

Comment: And this article which I found in the references of the previous article: http://worrydream.com/refs/Altmann%20-%20Hamilton,%20Rodrigues,%20and%20the%20Quaternion%20Scandal.pdf